# Does it exist any function to dynamically create variables from the key value pair of an array?

Tags: php

Let's say I have this array,

```
$array = array(
    'name' => 'hermet',
    'emails' => array ('hermet@example.com',
                     'hermet@example.net');
);
```

So this way `echo $array ['name'] == 'hermet'` prints true. I would like to know if there is a function already embedded in PHP that let me do this:

```
echo $name == 'hermet'; // obviously 'false'

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $aux = $key;
    $$aux = $value; 
}   

echo $name == 'hermet'; // now prints 'true'
```

It seems to work even with a multidimensional array but I don't know if PHP has already any function to do that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be looking for [extract](http://php.net/extract)

```
$array = array(
    'name' => 'hermet',
    'emails' => array ('hermet@example.com',
                     'hermet@example.net')
);

extract($array);

var_dump($emails);
echo $name;
```

-- EDIT: If you are concerned about Paul's remark, supply EXTR_SKIP to the second argument of extract, that way it won't overwrite variable in case you've already defined it prior to calling extract.

```
$name = 'jason';
extract($array, EXTR_SKIP);

echo $name; // still 'jason'
```

Comment: +1 Also beware that if the user has any controller over your array keys (IE. posting a form or reading them from a database) you should not use this (or your above loop), since a user could overwrite any variable they wanted with any value.

Comment: @PaulP.R.O. Thanks for mentioning that :)

Comment: Ok, in this case the user has no control whatsoever on the name of the keys but it is good to know, thanks guys